# Tkinter button gets variable not found error

Tags: python, loops, datetime, tkinter

I am trying to create a program with tkinter that allows an employee to click a "clock in" button which grabs the current time and creates a new button "clock out" which upon clicking the clock out button grabs the current time again and then displays total hours by the timedelta of each of these button clicks. My problem is that the program doesn't return the total hours worked due to the "ClockedIn" variable not being defined. I believe it is a problem with the arrangement of code but I am stuck. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am a beginner coder and appreciate any feedback. Thank you.

My code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import datetime
window = Tk()


def onclick1():
    label = tk.Label(text ="Clocked In")
    label.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
    label2 = tk.Label(text = time.strftime("%I:%M"))
    label2.grid(row =1, column = 5)
    CLockedIn = time.time()
    button2 = ttk.Button(window, text ="Clock Out")
    button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    button2.config(command = onclick2)

def onclick2():
        label4 = tk.Label(text ="Clocked Out")
        label4.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
        ClockOut = time.time()
        label5 = tk.Label(text = time.strftime("%I:%M"))
        label5.grid(row =2, column = 5)
        Hours = int(ClockOut-CLockedIn)
        HoursLabel= tk.Label(Hours)
        HoursLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 4)

btn1 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Clock In")
btn1.grid(row=1,column=1)
btn1.config(command= onclick1)



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: You can pass the `ClockedIn` to `onclick2()` function and so don't need a global variable.  Also better use `datetime.now()` instead of `time.time()`.  Then `ClockOut - ClockedIn` will be a `timedelta` instance which can show you the time difference in `h:mm:ss` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says you need to add a global variable `CLockedIn`. It is not good practice to use capital letters for variables. When you add the time difference it will show the difference in `seconds` not in `hours`.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import datetime
window = Tk()

clocked_in = 0
def onclick1():
    global clocked_in
    label = tk.Label(text ="Clocked In")
    label.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
    label2 = tk.Label(text = time.strftime("%I:%M"))
    label2.grid(row =1, column = 5)
    clocked_in = time.time()
    button2 = ttk.Button(window, text ="Clock Out")
    button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    button2.config(command = onclick2)

def onclick2():
        label4 = tk.Label(text ="Clocked Out")
        label4.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
        clocked_out = time.time()
        label5 = tk.Label(text = time.strftime("%I:%M"))
        label5.grid(row =2, column = 5)
        hours = int(clocked_out-clocked_in)
        hoursLabel= tk.Label(text=hours)
        hoursLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 4)

btn1 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Clock In")
btn1.grid(row=1,column=1)
btn1.config(command= onclick1)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Prudhvi already [explained in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61338209/11228541) that the root cause of your main issue is that `CLockedIn` is a local variable that gets destroyed after exiting the function's scope.  They also alluded to the fact that subtracting two `time.time` objects will result in second not hours. Here are some suggestions on how to clean up their presentation in the button labels:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time


def onclick1():
    global CLockedIn
    CLockedIn = time.time()
    label = tk.Label(text="Clocked In")
    label.grid(row=1, column=3)
    label2 = tk.Label(text=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z', time.localtime(CLockedIn)))
    label2.grid(row=1, column=5)
    button2 = ttk.Button(window, text="Clock Out")
    button2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    button2.config(command=onclick2)


def onclick2():
    global ClockOut
    ClockOut = time.time()
    label4 = tk.Label(text="Clocked Out")
    label4.grid(row=2, column=3)
    label5 = tk.Label(text=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z', time.localtime(ClockOut)))
    label5.grid(row=2, column=5)
    Hours = (ClockOut - CLockedIn)
    HoursLabel = tk.Label(text=f"{int(Hours//3600)} hrs {int((Hours%3600)//60)} mins {round((Hours%3600)%60,2)} secs")
    HoursLabel.grid(row=3, column=4)


window = Tk()

ClockOut, CLockedIn = None, None
btn1 = ttk.Button(window, text="Clock In")
btn1.grid(row=1, column=1)
btn1.config(command=onclick1)

window.mainloop()
```